# How to make google chart API responsive?

Tags: google-visualization

I am creating two charts Line Chart and Donut Chart on same HTML Page using Google JS API. But these charts are not responsive. How can I make those charts as responsive?

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some tips...

Answer (score 0):

The Google Charts API was probably not designed with responsiveness in mind, specifically. The default size of the chart is to fill the element it's being rendered into, so you can just use CSS and Media Queries like you would normally do to make a responsive design.

The only real problem is that once the chart is drawn, it doesn't change it's size in a desktop window resize-type scenario. In [Angular Google Chart](https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart) we listen for the window's resize event and redraw the chart.

I've seen some of the resize strategy paired with a bit of JavaScript to keep the chart the same aspect ratio no matter how wide it is.

Anything more specific will need a more detailed question. I am intentionally not including any code for this answer, because whatever I write will probably be wrong for your situation.